How to match one surface to another and the making a cut from it?
How can I easily create a groove in the surface of the larger object which matches the smaller one?
I have hundreds of these to do so dont want to be manipulating individual points.
Is there a modifier which will work with a boolean?


Hello, yes try it with a Boolean modifier or with the Knife Project tool?

Hello, FresWH, If you want to automate this for your large number of objects,  we need some design constraints: rules defining the extents and position of the grooves, with respect to their target objects.  It would really help us if you edited this post  to get as close as you can to that.
